# Google App Engine, Load Testing on the Appspot server

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am a beginner in GAE and still evaluating if I should use this for my school project. I need to show that how an application can be scalable, the definition I wanna use here is whether it can serve 1000s of users concurrently.

Now load testing is one way of doing it. But load is futile when Google will scale out the application to a number of different instances depending on the load.

So hence, I am thinking of simulating data store read/writes access memcache etc to show the scalability prospects of the application.

Now, using JUnit Test is a good way to do this. But they can only be run locally. Is there a way to run them on the server, the actual production environment? If that can be done, then I can just write these tests and execute them via eclipse and I should be done!

The other way is to use functional testing with selenium to simulate the load and actual user conditions but this would most probably crash my computer and also not be concurrent.

The other option is to use a python load testing script and use sample json data to throw requests at the server urls. This however I tried but I cant test the options where genuine user interaction is needed since the live site requires a google sign in.

Any ideas where do I proceed to?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question.  I don't understand the part about load being futile - You expect that Google will scale out the application to handle 1000s of users... so... in essence you just want to prove that the answer is yes?  Are you trying to determine how many users you can serve on a single instance?  When you run on App Engine, GAE will spin up more instances.  One concern is about running out of quota before your test finishes.

Comment: Yes thats true, but what I mean is is that there should be a way of conducting datastore tests at the server levels to simulate some form of behaviour,lets say to read/write entities 100 times, or some stuff like that, may be the question was not framed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at either Siege (http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/) or JMeter (http://jmeter.apache.org/) for doing remote testing of your apps. The problem is though that you will hit the limit of your actual testing machine before you hit the limit of what you're trying to test so a lot of people spin up a few EC2 instances and run the load tests from there. Seige is very simple, it just reads a list of urls from a text file and clobbers the server as hard as you tell it to. JMeter lets you create more robust tests that can do things like log into a server and log more fine grained details about how your app behaves.

Those are the two best free and easy to use tools out there (IMHO).

Comment: Going to point out here that with a whole of of GAE experience, the slow part *IS* the datastore, that's the part you actually need to load test. You can ruin your speed by making too many datastore requests. Gets are cheap, queries are not. Set up JMeter, record a bunch of urls, hit it for a while and then go in and look at appstats to see where your latency is.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you really want to simulate datastore operations.

You can write a HTTP request handler that loads your junit tests and calls them, then either dump the results to log or as the HTTP result.

If they take a long time to run, you can run them on a backend instance.

Along the lines of Rick's suggestion,  you can also probably run a test on a backend instance that makes HTTP requests to your frontend instances using the async HTTP API, and cause your front end instances to do a lot of work, if that's what you need to simulate.